# Jquery Data Table from csv file

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to fill my Jquery Dtable from a csv file using php to parse the csv and then trying to render with Dtable, but doesn't seems to work(

```
TypeError: nCell is undefined
[Break On This Error]   nCell.className += ' '+oCol.sClass;
```

). What would be an other workaround to get it work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#result_table').dataTable();
            } );
</script>


<?php 
echo "
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='display' id='result_table' width='100%'>
            <thead>
                <th>Zeit</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Refferer</th>         
            </thead>\n\n";
$f = fopen("../logfile.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n    <tfoot>
        <tr>
                <th>Zeit</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Refferer</th>     
        </tr>
    </tfoot></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Where is the <tbody> tag in the code? Is it part of your CSV file (which am sure is not)? Can you rectify the code again.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, it looks like you are missing the tags.

```
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

I would check the HTML output in Firebug or View Source after it reads the CSV to make sure that it is a valid table.

Comment: doesn't help. I suppose the rendering is not proper

Comment: Yeah, foreach ($line as $cell) { makes me think that it is only putting one cell per row. All rows need 4 cells in your case.

Comment: maybe you are right when I var_dump("<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell)."</td>"); than it look like there is a cell in plus

Comment: yepp there was an empty line in the csv file